# Deep reverse function in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a deep reverse function in Lisp, with only relying on the original reverse function that Lisp provides, and some other common things. I think it is kind of easier to do it using a map, such as:

```
(defun deep-reverse (list)
  (if (listp list)
      (mapcar #'deep-reverse
              (reverse list))
      list))
```

But what about without using those maps, or other constructions. Just by relying on stuff such as `if`, `reverse`, `append`, `null`, `nil`, `listp`, `atom`, `cons`, `car`, `cdr`, etc. The basic stuff. I can do it for a one level reverse, like this:

```
(defun reverse (list)
  (if (null list)
     'nil
      (append (reverse (cdr list))
              (cons (car list) 'nil))))
```

But how can I achieve something like that for deep reverse? What I mean by deep reverse is, if the input to the function is `((1 2 3) (4 5 6))`, the output should be `((6 5 4) (3 2 1))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
(defun deep-reverse (list)
  (if (consp list)
      (nconc (deep-reverse (cdr list))
             (list (deep-reverse (car list))))
      list))
(deep-reverse  '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
==> ((6 5 4) (3 2 1))
```

I needed to make a few changes compared to your version:

1. Call `deep-reverse` on *both* `car` and `cdr`.
2. Use [`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm) instead of [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm) to avoid unnecessary consing.
3. Rename `reverse` to `deep-reverse`.
4. Branch recursion on `consp`, not `null`.